# How to raise the power of each array in a 2d numpy array to a power of each element in a 1d numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array filled with arrays and I want to raise each array to the power of corresponding elements in another array. To better show what I want to do here's an example:

```
a = np.array([2,2,2,2]) 
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c = np.ones((4,4))*a
```

The output that i'm trying to get is:

```
print(c[0]**b[0],c[1]**b[1],c[2]**b[2],c[3]**b[3])
```

Which would be:
[2. 2. 2. 2.] [4. 4. 4. 4.] [8. 8. 8. 8.] [16. 16. 16. 16.]

But I'm trying to do this without using loops, I've tried this:

```
np.power(c,b)
```

But this is the result:
`[[ 2.  4.  8. 16.] [ 2.  4.  8. 16.] [ 2.  4.  8. 16.] [ 2.  4.  8. 16.]]`

I've been looking online for some sort of solution for this problem, but I could not find anything or at least I could not phrase it properly enough to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of broadcasting rules, which line up dimensions on the right. Two arrays of shapes

```
4, 4
   4
```

A do not give what you want. But the following will:

```
4, 4
4, 1
```

You can add a unit dimension like this:

```
c**b[:, None,]
```

or

```
c**b.reshape(-1, 1)
```

or any number of other ways.